# What is the best way in C++ to have a function return an error or a value?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have this function for reading a JSON file:

```cpp
json read_json_from_file(const std::string &path) {
  if(!file_exists(path)) {
    // return error
  }
  
  json j = json(path);
  return j;
}
```

For the line where an error is returned what is the most C++ way of doing it?

I thought about returning `NULL` or `nullptr`.

I saw a project which used `std::optional` but it didn't make much sense for me. This would imply "this could possibly return something", instead of "this function could return an error". The code would be like the one below.

```cpp
std::optional<json> read_json_from_file(const std::string &path) {
  if(!file_exists(path)) {
    return std::nullopt;
  }
  
  json j = json(path);
  return j;
}
```

And then, we would use this way:

```cpp
auto s = "path/to/file.json";
auto j = read_json_file(s);
if(j == std::nullopt) { // std::nullopt as an example of using the std::optional
  // do something because we got an error
  std::cout << "error: could not open file " << s << std::endl;
  return ERROR;
}
```

This project doesn't use exceptions and we have no intention of doing that. Instead, I am looking for a way of returning errors and not losing context. See example below where I have no context after the function call:

```cpp
std::optional<json> read_json_from_file(const std::string &path) {
  if(!file_exists(path)) {
    return std::nullopt;
  }

  if(get_file_extension(path) != "json") {
    return std::nullopt;
  }

  json j = json(path);
  return j;
}
```

What is the best way to not lose context and don't use exceptions here?

Comment: This is very close to a code review and opinionated answers. "_What is the best way_" ...

Comment: By "not losing context" do you mean "the caller can distinguish between a number of different types of error" or something else?

Comment: I updated the title to more accurately reflect what you're asking, and hopefully avoid getting closed as "opinionated" but you can revert if you want

Comment: Might want to check [tl::expected](https://github.com/TartanLlama/expected), which implements the [P0323R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0323r3.pdf) proposal. Just be careful, it adds a few extensions on top of it that you might want to avoid if you want to be compatible with the possible eventual adoption of the proposal.

Comment: Throw an exception.

Comment: You are looking for something like `Result` in rust lang? I find someone has made a similar library in c++. Or you may manually write a `Status ` class to wrapper return code, and have an extra function argument reference as true function return, this is a skill mostly used in Google's source code.

Comment: This question more belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RichardCritten OP says project isn't using exceptions

Comment: This question is a lot more specific than the title suggests. [Here's a starting point using `std::variant`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/s6Ra55I6DeIwFW3z)

Comment: @Horus -  If you expect the caller to unpick which error condition occurred from several possibilities, then there are few ways to avoid code artefacts ("ugly switch cases", "ugly if/else tests") to do that. If you want to avoid such code, you might want to return (say) a `std::variant<json, ErrorObject>`, where `ErrorObject` provides member functions for reporting the error, or `std::variant<json, FileError, MemoryError, etc>`. Not much benefit in that over throwing exceptions (except that the caller can passively ignore an error condition and not have to explicitly swallow an exception).

Comment: Personally I think using `std::error_code` somewhat like `std::filesystem` can be cleaner than `std::variant<...>` if you can't do exceptions. But there are no truly great solutions IMO.

Comment: Why this question is closed? I want to give an answer to introduce the newly added boost library: leaf, I think it maybe a noticeable solution.

Comment: _"...This project doesn't use exceptions and we have no intention of doing that..."_ are you just not using exceptions or compiling with the (compiler specific) no expection option set?

Answer (score 2):

> For the line where an error is returned what is the most C++ way of doing it?

`throw` an exception. If that is not an option, then return a `std::variant<json, errorInfo>` instead, where `errorInfo` is whatever you need to describe the error (an error code, an error message string, a class/struct with multiple details about the error, etc).

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin lots of if/else and/or case statements where the caller tries to workout if the error is recoverable or not. Followed by passing any non-recoverable error(s) up the call stack to the next level etc.  Not forgetting the problem that exceptions were introduced to solve - the non-testing of error-codes (producing hard to find errors long after the 1st error was mistakenly ignored).  So add more code reviews to your plans.